# Responsive Hover Effect With Sprite Image - Can't Make It Work

Tags: css, image, background, hover, sprite

I went through all the threads on stackoverflow in searching for an answer on this but for the life of me I couldn't get it to work.

I'm trying to create an image hover effect with a sprite image.
I need the image to be responsive.

The code I'm using for this is:

### CSS

```
#sprite {
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/AJ8dt9d.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat;
    display:block; /* Necessary, since A is not a block element */
    height:500px;
    max-width:500px;
    margin:auto;
}

#sprite:hover {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/AJ8dt9d.jpg) 50% 100% no-repeat;
    display:block; /* Necessary, since A is not a block element */
    height:500px;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div id="sprite"><a href="link.html"></a></div>
```

And here's the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/nhsca4c6/

Answer (score 0):

You can use @media screen to make responsive images and batter approach is to use all divs with fix width in their max-width media query and out side this you should use width in percentage

For screen with  1024px max width

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
   #sprite {
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/AJ8dt9d.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat;
    display:block; /* Necessary, since A is not a block element */
    height:500px;
    max-width:500px;
    margin:auto;
}

#sprite:hover {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/AJ8dt9d.jpg) 50% 100% no-repeat;
    display:block; /* Necessary, since A is not a block element */
    height:500px;
}
}
```

For screen with  720px max width

```
@media screen and (max-width: 720px){
 #sprite {
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/AJ8dt9d.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat;
    display:block; /* Necessary, since A is not a block element */
    height:300px;
    max-width:300px;
    margin:auto;
}

#sprite:hover {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/AJ8dt9d.jpg) 50% 100% no-repeat;
    display:block; /* Necessary, since A is not a block element */
    height:300px;
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have a fiddle example to see it live? I tried using the code above but it didn't make the image responsive. If I set a fixed width instead of max-width the image doesn't to smaller screens. Should I use some kind of wrapper/container for the div?

Comment: change size of window i only make it responsive for two screen you can define as many you need

Comment: The image is still not responsive, it just changes dimension and trims itself when decreasing the window size, but it doesn't act like a normal image.

Comment: The hover effect is also not working well with it, I need the image to be swapped completely from top to bottom as if you were using 2 different images.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look
http://jsfiddle.net/nhsca4c6/2/
Main thing that you set fixed width for element.
Also should be used

```
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: This doesn't work since setting a fixed width kills the responsiveness and will will not appear well on mobile.